# Material UI Grid do not work on Chrome DevTools Device Toolbar

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, css-grid

Im using MUI v5 + React + Typescript.

When Im using Grid system I define some options like `xs sm md lg` etc for set item's width etc.
If I set only `xs` or `sm`, its works good. But If I set `md`, other options that under `md` like `xs sm` are NOT working when Im using DevTool Device toolbar and set some mobile response. But If Im not using DevTool and just changing a size of Chrome's window its working ok. Also its NOT working on iOS and Android phones.

Also when Im using useMediaQuery for example `useMediaQuery('(max-width:576px)')` its also NOT working. If i set `max-width:960` (`md` properties) its working ok.

When I create an empty MIU 5 React TS project and using this Grid system its working ok.

How can I find whats wrong with my project?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QifT.jpg

Example code is:

```
root: {
        flexGrow: 1
    },
```

```
<Grid
            container
            direction="row"
            justifyContent="space-between"
            className={classes.root}>
            <Grid item md={6} sm={6} xs={6} lg={6}>
                some inner code
            </Grid>
            <Grid item md={5} sm={6} xs={5} lg={4}>
                inner code
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: Can you add the code when you apply `xs` or `sm` and when you apply `md`. Are you applying all of those or just 1 option? Share the code.

Comment: A ```md``` overrides ```sm``` and ```xs``` if it applied all of those options on screen width <500px

Comment: When it goes wrong, what do you see in the developer tools, Elements CSS section? Can you add a screenshot of that?

Comment: I've added screen. I set 250 px window width in DevTools and as you can see its defined only min width 600 and 900 px. But in code its defined xs sm and md too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how it works but after build app the problem is gone.